# Let G be a group of $2\times 2$ non-singular matrices under multiplication over the field $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of $2\times 2$ non-singular matrices under multiplication over the field $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Define a map $f:G \to \mathbb{R}^*$ (where $\mathbb{R}^*$ is a group of non zero real under multiplication) s.t. $f(A)= |A|$. Then $o(\ker f)$ is

a) $12$

b) $24$

c) $48$

d) none of the above

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?

Comment: O(G)=(3^2-1) (3^2-3) =48

Comment: O(ker f) will be those element of gG which is mapped to identity matrices over Z3

Comment: @Halima.Khatun; $\ker f=\{A:|A|=1\}$ where $|A|=$ order of $A$.So then $\ker f=\{I\}$ where $I$ is identity

Comment: @BenStokes I think $|A|$ is intended to mean determinant, not order.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Ker$(f)$ is nothing but $SL_2(\mathbb Z_3)$,Can you compute the cardinality of $SL_2(\mathbb Z_3)$?

**Edit:** I think you know how to compute the order of $GL_n(\mathbb F_p)$,to compute the order of $SL_n((\mathbb F_p)$ note that there is a 'natural' onto group homomorphism $f: GL_n((\mathbb F_p) \to \mathbb F_p^*$ (What is the map?) and hence apply the first isomorphism theorem  to compute the cardinality of $SL_n((\mathbb F_p)$... Still if you don't get it you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/order-of-general-and-special-linear-groups-over-finite-fields?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: no...plz help me

Comment: $\ker f=\{A:|A|=1\}$ where $|A|=$ order of $A$.So then $\ker f=\{I\}$ where $I$ is identity

Comment: Am I missing something?Where from do you get $SL_2$

Comment: Determinant, not order.  Order is not a homomorphism.

Comment: Dear @BenStokes: Recall that $o(ab) \neq o(a)o(b)$ unless there are assumptions on $G$ like abelian etc..Hence order can't be homomorphism as pointed out by Robert Israel.

Answer (score 0):

A member of $\ker f$ is a matrix $\pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d\cr}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z_3$ and $ad - bc \equiv 1 \mod 3$.
For any $a \ne 0$, and any $b$ and $c$, you need $d \equiv (1+bc)/a \mod 3$.  That makes $2 \times 3 \times 3 = 18$ choices.
On the other hand, if $a = 0$ you can take any $d$, but you need $bc=1$, thus either $b=c=1$ or $b=c=2$.  This makes $6$ additional choices, for a total of $24$.

Comment: thanks..do there have any general rule to compute such kind of problem