# Cardinality of the subset of End(V)

Tags: linear-algebra

If $F$ is a finite field and $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$ then we have to find the cardinality of the set $$S=\{f\in End(V) : fv=v \text{ for some non-zero }v\}$$

I have no clue where to start from. Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: First observe that $f\in End (V)$ fixes a non zero vector iff $f-Id$ is singular. So it suffices to count the number of singular endomorphisms.

Comment: thanks, got it!

Answer (score 0):

I have missed you thought twice. This is the third time.
This is equivalent to finding matrix $(A-I)x =0$ for some $x$ in $F^n$.
 Consequently, the cardinality is the subset $H$ consisted by all matrices $A$ which satisfies that $rank(A-I) ＜ n$.

---

Upgradation: The key of  question is to find how many invertible matrices. This has been solved. Look over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/order-of-general-and-special-linear-groups-over-finite-fields)

This address is being provided by [the order of elements in $GL_{n}(F)$ over a field.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664462/the-order-of-elements-in-gl-nf-over-a-field)

Comment: But I'm not looking to find the cardinality of End(V). I'm looking to find the cardinality of the subset of End(V) that fixes at least one non-zero vector.

Comment: @User2592 I am not sure what do you mean "fix at least...". You mean if there is a non-zero vector $a$, you want the cardinality of a subset $A$ which has $a$?

Comment: @User2592 or you mean a subset $A$(not a subspace) need to contain at least one non-zero vector?