# Why its is a linear combination of $u_1 $ and $u_2$?

Tags: group-theory

Im posting this question since this user is not active for many years

I have some confusion in the  given answer [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/order-of-general-and-special-linear-groups-over-finite-fields)

My doubt given below  marked in red line

[image]

**My  doubt** : we know that 3rd row is linearly independent from first and second row that implies it cannot be linear  combination $u_1$ and $u_2$

But here im not getting  that

Why its is a linear  combination of $u_1 $ and $u_2$?

Comment: It is not a linear combination of $u_1,u_2$. That is what the text says

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου  **NOT**  word is not mention in given answer

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your question. Do you think that the answer you refer to is wrong?

Comment: The text says that $u_3$ can be anything apart from a linear combination of $u_1,u_2$. So $u_3$ is not a linear combination of $u_1,u_2$

Comment: okss may be my english is weak @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου  but it should be written like this...... the third row can be anything but not a linear combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$....Here i have add **no**  word

Comment: Yes it is a matter of expression. The way it is writen may be confusing for someone not native english speaker (like me and you) but it is correct

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/what-is-the-difference-between-nothing-but-anything-but-and-everything-bu

Comment: thanks u @HansLundmark now got its....   my english is weak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that we want the matrix to be non-singular, so we can't have any of the rows being linearly dependent.  For the first three rows not to be linearly dependent translates into the third row not  being a linear combination of the first two.  Etc...