# $|GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k}})|$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I want to calculate the order of the group $G = GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k}})$ consist of all invertible matrices size $n\times n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k}}$ with $p$ a prime number, $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Where $\mathbb{Z}_{m} = \{\overline{0},\overline{1},\cdots,\overline{m-1}\}$ is the ring of integers modulo $m$

I know if we take $n=1$ we have that $|GL(1,\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k}})| = p^{k-1}(p-1)$

But if we take $n>1$, I can't calculate it.

I tried to do it using the fact that the determinant of $A\in G$ must be invertible. In other words $p \nmid det(A)$. But I'm stuck

Can someone help me?

Comment: First: Try to solve $k=1$, $n$ arbitrary

Comment: Well, I'll try it!, thanks!

Comment: When $k=1$ we have a field, and this is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34271)

Comment: Thank you so much!