# Show that the order of a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ divides the order of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{F_3})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

This problem comes from Johns Hopkins University Spring 2020 algebra qualifying. 
Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Prove that the order of $G$ divides
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(3^n-1\right)\left(3^n-3\right) \ldots\left(3^n-3^{n-1}\right) .
$$
Hint: Use reduction modulo 3.


My idea: Assuming $\pi_p:\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{F_3})$ performed by mod 3 ,so it is sufficient to prove $\pi_p$ provides a injection between finite subgroups  of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ to $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{F_3})$ , for which I cannot give a proof.

I have found it have been solved on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup
,where it provides a huge paper concerning some advanced method. But I havn't learn algebraic number theory. So I wonder some simple method for graduates level students.

Comment: Some related problem follows:  number of special linear group:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/order-of-general-and-special-linear-groups-over-finite-fields?rq=1

Comment: paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02684586#Bib1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g$ be a finite order nontrivial element of the kernel of $SL(n, {\mathbb Z})\to SL(n, {\mathbb Z}_{p})$, $p\ge 3$, prime; I am using the topologist notation for finite abelian groups. (There is nothing special about $p=3$.) Our goal is to reach a contradiction. (The argument is due to Minkowski or to Schur, I am not sure.)

We have $g=I+pA$, where $A\ne  {\mathbf 0}$ is an integer matrix. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $g$ has prime order $q$. We have (by applying the binomial formula):
$$
g^q= (I+p A)^q= I + {q\choose 1} pA + {q\choose 2} (pA)^2 + {q\choose 3} (pA)^3+... + (pA)^q= I.
$$
Factoring out $pA$ (and canceling $p$), we obtain
$$
A\underbrace{({q\choose 1} I + {q\choose 2}  p A + {q\choose 3} (pA)^2 +...  + (pA)^{q-1})}_{B}= {\mathbf 0}.
$$
If $B$ is invertible (as a real matrix), we obtain that $A= {\mathbf 0}$, a contradiction. Hence, $B$ has
zero determinant. Reducing modulo $p$, we obtain that the determinant of $B$ is $q^n$ modulo $p$. There are
now two cases to consider:

(1) $q\ne p$ (recall that $p, q$ are prime). Hence, $\det B$ is nonzero modulo $p$, which is a contradiction.

(2) $q=p$,
$$
B= {p\choose 1} I + {p\choose 2} p A + {p\choose 3} (pA)^2 +...  + (pA)^{p-1}. 
$$

Note that if $p=3$, we have
$$
B= 3\ I + 3^2 A+ (3A)^2. 
$$

Observe that each summand in the matrix $B$ is divisible by $p$. Moreover, since $p=q\ge 3$, each summand of $B$,  except for the first one,  ${p \choose 1} I $, is divisible by $p^2$. Hence, $B= p(I + pC)$ for some integer matrix $C$. Repeating the argument in Case 1, we obtain that $\det(I+pC)=0$ but  $\det(I+pC)\ne 0$ modulo $p$. A contradiction.